# QGIS how to combine a single line and a centered short and constant offset arrow line

Tags: qgis, symbology, geometry-generator

I am making a flow map where I want to have a double geometry: a single line and a centered offset arrow line.
For the moment, I use a buffer but of course I don't get the desired effect of an arrow of constant length. With the buffer the length of the arrow depends on the segment.

[image]

```
difference(
  difference(
     make_line(
       start_point($geometry),
       centroid(
          offset_curve(
             $geometry, 
             length($geometry)/100.0
          )
       ),
    end_point($geometry)
    ),
    buffer(start_point($geometry), 0.1)
  ),
  buffer(end_point( $geometry), 0.1)
```

)

[image]

Comment: Can't you use an oriented vector symbol as the (long) arrow? Point geometry as line centroid + offset & orient it with the line azimuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can interpolate the start and end points of your arrow line along the geometry of the feature, insert a mid-point which is offset from those and then offset all of them from the original geometry.

Better explained by this image:

[image]

Then add the arrow symbology:

[image]

Expression:

```
offset_curve(  
    make_line(                            -- make a line of the following 3 points
        line_interpolate_point( 
            $geometry,
            length($geometry) / 2 - 50    -- make a point X map units before the midpoint of the line geometry
        ),
        
        line_interpolate_point(
            offset_curve(
                $geometry,
                length($geometry) / 75
            ),
            length($geometry) / 2         -- make a point halfway along the geometry, offset by X map units
        ),
        
        line_interpolate_point(
            $geometry,
            length($geometry) / 2 + 50    -- make a point X map units after the midpoint of the line geometry
        )
    ),
    length($geometry)/100                 -- offset the line from the original geometry
)
```

###### Applying the expression

The expression is applied to a Geometry Generator symbol layer as shown here:

[image]

You might want the offsets to be a fixed distance, rather than relative to the line length, but that is a design choice that's up to you of course.

###### Arrow per line segment

If you want the arrow to appear per line segment, rather than for the complete feature, you can use this expression:

```
collect_geometries(
    with_variable('segments',
        segments_to_lines($geometry),
        
        array_foreach(
            generate_series(1, num_geometries(@segments)),
            
            with_variable('current_segment',
            
                geometry_n(@segments, @element),
                offset_curve(
                    make_line(
                        line_interpolate_point(
                            @current_segment,
                            length(@current_segment) / 2 - 50
                        ),
                        
                        line_interpolate_point(
                            offset_curve(
                                @current_segment,
                                length(@current_segment) / 75
                            ),
                            length(@current_segment) / 2
                        ),
                        
                        line_interpolate_point(
                            @current_segment,
                            length(@current_segment) / 2 + 50
                        )
                    ),
                    length(@current_segment)/50
                )
            )
            
        )
        
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping but I am lost in the UI of QGIS. Can you add a screenshot of the symbology window ?

Comment: Have done.  I hope that is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Marker Line** instead of **Geometry Generator**. Set the **Marker** placement to **On central point of segments**, and set the line offset. Then you can define two symbols inside the marker, first a line like this:

[image: 1]

And then a triangle like this:

[image: 2]

The result:

[image: 3]